# Real example of inline edit

Tags: design-patterns, gui-design, inline-edit

I am looking for an example of use of inline edit pattern (one of the Yahoo! Patterns library) for my work in the University. I founded examples of Table Edit (like spreadsheet) but this patterns works with just one single field

Comment: Huh? Ever looked at a spreadsheet? Not like they bring up a dialog when you want to change the value of a cell? And even though spreadsheets usually do not get their data from a database, they still need to store your data somewhere so the same kind of issues apply as when you show data from a table in a grid.

Comment: Add this to you question (which comes from your own comment): "I am looking for an example of use of inline edit pattern (one of the Yahoo! Patterns library) for my work in the University. I founded examples of Table Edit (like spreadsheet) but this patterns works with just one single field"

Comment: [Trello](https://trello.com/) has also some nice inline editing...

Answer (score 2):

You can go to https://docs.google.com/ Create New > Spreadsheet

Here's an example & tutuorial for php/jquery inline edit:
http://papermashup.com/demos/inline-editing/

Not exactly sure what you are looking for.

Comment: That is great but it's Table Edit Pattern, a variation of the pattern I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Our projects at work is run with [GreenHopper](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH050/GreenHopper+5.0+Release+Notes), which fascilitates inline editing in almost every view. Simple, easy and makes time management fun!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I will explian myself better... I am looking for an example of use of inline edit pattern (one of the Yahoo! Patterns library) for my work in the University. I founded examples of Table Edit (like spreadsheet) but this patterns works with just one single field

Comment: This is probably not the best place to post your question then. You might find better help from the yahoo library community, or an API user group. http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/community.html

Comment: I founded it right here! When I put a comment on an answer, I realize that I can edit my comment using inline edit pattern.

In that pattern there is no need to left page for edit an item, and that is just the functionality included in this forum.

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: OK. But please update you're question so you have a better chance of relevant replies. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

On Flickr you can edit your photo titles and captions directly from your photostream page and on photo pages without going to a separate edit page.